# Delphi XE5 choose to deploy to a real device not to emulator

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

In Delphi XE5, how do I choose to deploy to a real device and not to the emulator?

Comment: Connect the device, and choose it as the target. (It helps to know what platform you're talking about, BTW.) http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Activating_and_Configuring_the_Target_Platform

Comment: Also see [Android Mobile Application Development](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Android_Mobile_Application_Development), which despite the name has a table and links for configuring the development environment for your device.

Comment: Make sure you have the Mobile add on pack for delphi installed.... Otherwise not even those doc's will help you.

Comment: To deploy it to an android device just connect it and choose the device as target. You can aslo make an apk file and install that on your device. You can create an apk file by deploying your project, you will find it in your project folder under debug or release depending what settings you have set.

Answer (score 1):

1. Before you can connect your android device to XE5 you need to install USB drivers. How to do that check out the link below section Installing the USB Driver for Your Android Device (Required):
   [Set up android](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Mobile_Tutorial%3a_Set_Up_Your_Development_Environment_on_Windows_PC_%28Android%29)
2. You also need to add the developer options to your device in your settings. How to do this depends on the device and you should just google this!

When you have done this you should be able to select your device in the project manager at android target!

Hope this helps!